# Compare rows across postgreSQL table and keep the row with the longest string in the column

Tags: postgresql

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
id      col1                             col2           code
3876    dexamethasone                   dexamethasone   A01AC | C05AA | D07AB | S01BA
3948    dexamethasone sodium phosphate  dexamethasone   A01AC | C05AA 
187834  dexamethasone sodium succinate  dexamethasone   H02AB | S01BA
352241  dexamethasone acetate           dexamethasone   D07AB | H02AB | S01BA
971608  dexamethasone phosphate         dexamethasone   H02AB
1010    insulin plus                    insulin         H02ABA | H02ABC
10101   paracet                         insul           H02A
10101   paracetamol                     insul           H02A
```

I would like to keep the row with longest code string (or minimum value of id), if col2 values are identical across the rows and if the id values are different. The rest of the rows remain as such.

The desired output is:

```
id      col1                             col2           code
3876    dexamethasone                   dexamethasone   A01AC | C05AA | D07AB | S01BA
1010    insulin plus                    insulin         H02ABA | H02ABC
10101   paracet                         insul           H02A
10101   paracetamol                     insul           H02A
```

For this issue, I have no starting point to try out. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81otatXD3MyhG7cyXCx7ZM/0)

```
with dup_ids as (
  select id
    from codes
   group by id
  having count(*) > 1
)
select distinct on (c.col2||case when d.id is null then '' else c.col1 end) c.*
  from codes c
  left join dup_ids d on d.id = c.id
 order by (c.col2||case when d.id is null then '' else c.col1 end), length(c.code) desc, c.id;
```

Comment: The query is not capturing both the rows of 'insul'  due to distinct on (col2).

Comment: @rshar  Sorry I missed that requirement.  I have updated the query to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can use `distinct on` and `row_number()`:

```
select distinct on (
    col2, 
    row_number() over(partition by col2, id order by id)
) t.*
from mytable t
order by
    col2, 
    row_number() over(partition by col2, id order by id),
    length(code) desc, 
    id
;
```